# Changing a WCF Endpoint

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, spring.net, wcf-endpoint

I have the following configuration from the initial examples shown the spring.net samples.

```
<wcf:channelFactory id="serverAppHost"
channelType="Contract.IHost, WcfService.Contract"
endpointConfigurationName="serverAppHostEndpoint" />

<client>
    <endpoint name="serverAppHostEndpoint" address="http://xxxxx:yyyyy/program/service/host" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding1" contract="Contract.IHost"/> 
</client>
```

My could reads as

```
IApplicationContext ctx = ContextRegistry.GetContext();
IHost val = (IHost)ctx.GetObject("serverAppHost");
```

All this works ok if my endpoint above has a correct IP address and port number.

I'm looking for a way in code to edit the endpoint to use the ip address and port number that will not be known at startup. Is there some way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved an problem similar to this. Basically, channel factories are not very flexible once your application is running. You're better off using a service proxy and dynamically setting the end point like this,

```
var client = new SampleClient();
client.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(url);
client.Open();
responseMessage = client.ServiceMethod(requestMessage);
```

SampleClient is your service proxy that visual studio generates for you. You'll need a WSDL to generate it from. You'll still need a dummy Client/Endpoint tag in your Web.config but this will be overwritten when you load in the dynamic URL.

Let me know if you need more details. I can walk you through the specific implementation.

Comment: This is standard wcf, i need to reference the client endpoint through the application context

Comment: Ok then, sorry I can't help you there. We just use spring for our wcf services. We wrap clients in a gateway that is injected to what ever needs them.