# Changing ip address on endpoint config

Tags: wcf

I imported a wsdl, and set up my web service. 
This works great, but now I want some flexibility of the IP address I use.

This seems simple enough, according to links 
[like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485851/changing-a-wcf-endpoint)

All i have to do is set the endpoint property to be what I want:

```
var client = new SampleClient();
client.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(url);
client.Open();
responseMessage = client.ServiceMethod(requestMessage);
```

but in my specific example, I don't have an "Endpoint" property that I can hit.
What am I missing?

```
PersonSearchWebServiceClient wc = new PersonSearchWebServiceClient();
PersonSearchResult r = wc.FindByPersonDetails(ps);
```

my wc object doesnt have an EndPoint property

Comment: you mean, that you are not seeing the Endpoint proerty on PersonSearchWebServiceClient class?

Comment: correct. I just dont have it

Comment: So I am guessing, it works. correct?

Comment: works great. just dont have the endpoint field

Comment: Does PersonSearchWebServiceClient inherit from ClientBase<T>?

Comment: yes it does. class PersonSearchWebServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<WSPersonSearch.IPersonSearchWebService>, WSPersonSearch.IPersonSearchWebService {

Answer (score 0):

There will be a setting in the web/app.config for the URL to the service that was imported, update this.

Answer (score 0):

Working code from my project (connect to Alfresco web service)

```
private AuthenticationServiceSoapPortClient getAuthService()
    {
        if (_authClient == null || _authClient.State != CommunicationState.Opened)
        {
            BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport); // For no-Ssl use None
            basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
            basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;
            basicHttpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;
            basicHttpBinding.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Default;
            var endPoint = new EndpointAddress(_alfrescoURL + "/" + _authEndPointPart);
            _authClient = new AuthenticationServiceSoapPortClient(basicHttpBinding, endPoint);
        }
        return _authClient;
    }
```

Comment: this will work. but not ideal because i overide all the basichttpbinding rules in my config